# How PDF viewer remembers the last page we were on when we back? I built app with android studio

Tags: android, pdf-viewer

How PDF viewer remembers the last page we were on when we back? I built app with android studio When I exit and go back to reading, I want to remember the page I was reading. Please guid me.
I used barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

public class PdfViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ActivityPdfViewBinding binding;

```
private String bookId;

private static final String TAG = "PDF_VIEW_TAG";

private int mCurrentPage = 0;
private final static String KEY_CURRENT_PAGE = "current_page";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityPdfViewBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    bookId = intent.getStringExtra("bookId");
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: BookId :"+bookId);

    loadBookDetails();

    binding.backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });


}

private void loadBookDetails() {
    Log.d(TAG, "loadBookDetails: Get PDF Url from database");
    //Step 1 : Get bookUrl using bookId
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Books");
    ref.child(bookId)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    //get bookUrl
                    String pdfUrl = ""+snapshot.child("url").getValue();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: PDF Url: "+pdfUrl);

                    //Step 2 : Load pdf using that url from Firebase storage
                    loadBookFromUrl(pdfUrl);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
}

private void loadBookFromUrl(String pdfUrl) {
    Log.d(TAG, "loadBookFromUrl: Get PDF from storage");
    
    StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(pdfUrl);
    reference.getBytes(Constants.MAX_BYTES_PDF)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                    //load pdf book using bytes
                    binding.pdfView.fromBytes(bytes)
                            .swipeHorizontal(false) // set false to scroll vertical
                            .defaultPage(mCurrentPage)
                            .onPageChange(new OnPageChangeListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
                                    //set current and total page in toolbar Text view subtitle
                                    int currentpage = page + 1;
                                    binding.toolbarSubtitleTv.setText(currentpage+"/"+pageCount);
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onPageChanged: "+currentpage+"/"+pageCount);
                                }
                            })
                            .onError(new OnErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onError: "+t.getMessage());
                                    Toast.makeText(PdfViewActivity.this, ""+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            })
                            .onPageError(new OnPageErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onPageError(int page, Throwable t) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onPageError: "+t.getMessage());
                                    Toast.makeText(PdfViewActivity.this, ""+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            })
                            .load();
                    binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: "+e.getMessage());
                    binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mCurrentPage = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(binding.pdfView.getCurrentPage())) ;
    outState.putInt(KEY_CURRENT_PAGE, mCurrentPage);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    mCurrentPage = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_CURRENT_PAGE);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SharedPreferences` here is an article that will help you get started.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Using `SharedPreferences` save `pdfUrl` when the user loads a pdf and `currentpage` every time the user changes pages.

When the app starts pull the `pdfUrl` and `currentpage` from `SharedPreferences`.
Use that to automatically load the pdf and jump to the saved page.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the same functionality which u want:

```
  override fun onPageChanged(page: Int, pageCount: Int) {
    editor = sharedPref.edit()
    editor.putInt("page", page)
    editor.apply()

    Toast.makeText(this@PdfActivity, "$page of $pageCount", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```